# Parsing of bits with XOR and Complement

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I have a problem to locate the number which occurs only once when all other numbers in the vector occur exactly thrice.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int singleNumber(vector<int>& nums) {

        int ones = 0;
        int twos = 0;

        for(const int& n : nums)
        {
            ones = (ones ^ n) & ~twos;
            twos = (twos ^ n) & ~ones;


            std::cout << ones << "\t" << twos << "\n";
        }

        return ones;
    }
};
```

For an input 2,2,5,5,9,2,5  The `ones` and `twos` take these values in various passes

```
Ones Twos
2     0
0     2
5     2
0     7
8     6
8     4
9     0
```

My question is How do i know that the algorithm would have worked as the XOR and Complement are yielding values like `0 7` , `8 4` and `8 6` in between the passes which are not even in the integer values being parsed.

I don't understand what's the theorem here which ensures that all these intermediate values will end up as being reduced to value which occurs only one in the input vector. How am i be fully sure that  yes all these intermediate results will get cleared and end up being the value which i want to detect.

Can anyone explain ?

I just understand that `ones = (ones ^ n) & ~twos;` means that add to `ones` if it doesn't exist in `twos` and `twos = (twos ^ n) & ~ones;` means that add to `twos` if it doesn't exist already in `ones`. That's all i understand. I don't understand the logic behind the intermediate unrelated values making way to value which is the result.

Comment: Hint: think of the corresponding bits of `twos` and `ones` as forming a 2-bit binary number.  Verify that the operation in the loop adds to this number the corresponding bit of `n`, mod 3.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations are confusing in that `ones` is updated using the existing value of `twos` but `twos` is updated using the updated value of `ones` in each iteration.

Try drawing a trace table like this (The former 3 columns are in decimal and the latter 6 are binary):

| existing ones | existing twos | n | n ^ ones | n ^ twos | ~existing twos | new ones | ~new ones | new twos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 0010 | 0010 | 1111 | 0010 | 1101 | 0000 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 0000 | 0010 | 1111 | 0000 | 1111 | 0010 |
| 0 | 2 | 5 | 0101 | 0111 | 1101 | 0101 | 1010 | 0010 |
| 5 | 2 | 5 | 0000 | 0111 | 1110 | 0000 | 1111 | 0111 |
| 0 | 7 | 9 | 1001 | 1110 | 1000 | 1000 | 0111 | 0110 |
| 8 | 6 | 2 | 1010 | 0100 | 1001 | 1000 | 0111 | 0100 |
| 8 | 4 | 5 | 1101 | 0001 | 1011 | 1001 | 0110 | 0000 |

To calculate the new value for the 7th column, do a bitwise AND on the 4th and 6th columns. To calculate the new value for the 9th column, do a bitwise AND on the 5th and 8th columns. Carry the binary values from the 7th and 9th columns to the new row.

You could also create temporary variables for each of these columns and include their values in your debug output.